# Interrupt when waiting on a blocking queue

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

I have a `Runnable` that runs from an `Executor`.
The runnable is blocked waiting in an `SychronousQueue.take`. How can I make sure the `take` will be interrupted when I do `executor.shutdown`?

Comment: ShutdownNow just does not execute rest of tasks.The problem is what will happen when the thread is blocked on `take`

Comment: The thing is the SynchronousQueue is probably empty, thus take() will block, until a put() will happen. Can you replace it with LinkedBlockingQueue?

Comment: But I need to block until something is put on the queue or the thread pool terminates

Comment: +1 Eugene, `shutdownNow` sends an interrupt to all running tasks, as well as preventing the execution of pending ones.

Comment: @Jim may be instead of doing executor.shutdown you could send a message with a payload that says that you must stop the service

Comment: In general for ExecutorServices, it is better to have jobs that already have their work cut out for them instead of letting them wait on some sort of queue. So, let the workers do work and let the Executor handle the work queue, but do not use the limited number of workers to wait instead of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 to @Eugene.  `ExecutorService.shutdown()` shuts the thread-pool down but any submitted jobs will continue to run until they finish.  If you use [`shutdownNow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29) instead, it will actually interrupt the threads.  This doesn't mean that they will stop immediately but it does mean that if they are blocked in `queue.take()` or their next call to `queue.take()` it will throw an `InterruptedException` so the thread can exit.

To quote from the Javadocs:

> Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution.
>
> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate.

When your threads are calling `queue.take()` they should have something like the following code:

```
  try {
      work = queue.take();
      ...
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      // re-interrupt the thread which is always a good pattern
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      // quit the processing thread
      return;
  }
```

Comment: But what will happen if the thread is **already** blocked in the `take`?

Comment: It will immediately throw @Jim.  I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this may be?

```
 executor.shutdown();
    if (!executor.awaitTermination(SHUTDOWN_TIME)) {
        executor.shutdownNow();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the [javadoc of take](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html#take%28%29) it will throw an `InterruptedException` when the thread waiting is interrupted. So you need to make sure that your executor implementation will call [Thread.interrupt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) on all it's owning threads on `shutdown`.